# Generar y leer archivo .txt javascripT

Tags: javascript, html, txt

Muy buenas a todos y muchas gracias de antemano.
mi problema es el siguiente, tengo un "marcador de dias sin accidnetes" en javascript y html y necesito guardar en un .txt el tiempo que esta funcionando el programa y el record de tiempo sin accidentes 
y no se como hacer eso ya busque por todos lados y no tengo respuesta que me sirva

```
//unas variables para almacenar el tiempo.

var milisegundos = 0;
var segundos = 0;
var minutos = 0;
var horas = 0;
var dias=0;

var aux_dias;
var aux_horas ;
var aux_minutos ;
var aux_segundos ;
var aux_milisegundos ;

var max_dias=0;
var max_horas = 0;
var max_minutos = 0;
var max_segundos = 0;
var max_milisegundos = 0;
```

esas son la variables que uso  y me gustaria que las maximas tomen valor de un txt porque esos valores nio deben de perderse por mas que se apague el quipo

---

ya pude realizar la lectura desde el .txt utilizando ajax
ahora lo que necesito es poder modificar esos .txt para guardar los nuevos datos y borrar los viejos

Comment: Lamento decirte que usando JS desde un navegador no podrás manipular directamente archivos de ninguna clase, por temas de seguridad. Vas a tener que buscar la forma de persistir los datos con algún sistema de BD, o leerlos desde un servicio web. Saludos

Comment: En JS no podrás abrir ni guardar ficheros locales sin que sea seleccionado manualmente por el usuario, por seguridad.

Comment: Lo que si puedes hacer es generar un txt y "descargarlo" localmente via enlace. La misma idea para cargar un archivo, debe ser el usuario quien seleccione el documento a subir.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que tu código en vanilla javascript funcionará solo mientras la página esté corriendo así que sería complicado... Luego hablas de que los valores no deben perderse aunque apaguen el equipo, y si así fuera entonces lo debería trabajar el servidor ... Usas node? El módulo file system te podrá ayudar